# Check if phrase is present in DIV style

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a DIV that contains a background image. In some cases this image is set "directly", in other cases it's a generated SVG. I want to be able to identify when a DIV contains the SVG-string.

My two DIVs:

```html
<div class="cover my-1" style="background-image: url('something.jpg');">Div 1 QQ</div>
<div class="cover my-2" style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc...=');">Div 2</div>
```

And I try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cover.my-1:contains(QQ)").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $(".cover.my-2:contains(svg+xml)").css("background-color", "yellow");  
});
```

So, DIV 1 changes as QQ is found. DIV 2 does not change as "svg+xml" is not found within the DIV-field it self (but is in the style). How do I identify the "svg+xml" in DIV 2?

I was hoping to identify the "svg+xml" within the style of the DIV

Answer (score 0):

`:contains` works only for the content of the element. You can use `filter` and `includes` to select your items with svg background

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cover.my-1:contains(QQ)").css("background-color", "yellow");
 $(".cover.my-2").filter((_, el) => $(el).css("background-image").includes("svg+xml")).css("background-color", "yellow");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover my-1" style="background-image: url('something.jpg');">Div 1 QQ</div>
<div class="cover my-2" style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc...=');">Div 2</div>
<div class="cover my-2" style="background-image: url('something.jpg');">Div 2 with class .cover.my-2, but without svg background is not selected</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works really well! Is there any way to not have the SVG image shown, if I use it like this:

`$("cover my-2").filter((_, el) => $(el).css("background-image").includes("svg+xml")).css("display", "none");`

When I do, the image shows for a brief period of time then disappears.

Comment: You can add attribute selector in css `.cover[style*="svg+xml"]{ display:none}`

Answer (score 0):

If you know upfront that you `svg+xml` is always going to be in the `style` attribute, you could use the [`[attr*=value]` attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). This will check if `value` is present in `attr`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cover.my-1:contains(QQ)").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $('.cover.my-2[style*="svg+xml"]').css("background-color", "yellow");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cover my-1" style="background-image: url('something.jpg');">Div 1 QQ</div>
<div class="cover my-2" style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc...=');">Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.
This will be turning the text color into **red** if it contains `data:image/svg+xml` and it will change the text color to **black** in case `data:image/svg+xml` is not available in the background-url link

> **Here is an example:** You can run the below snippet and check in this snippet
> The DIV contains SVG background image so on document load the text of the DIV
> will be in RED color

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('.cover').attr("style").indexOf('data:image/svg+xml') != -1){
    $('.cover').css({'color':'#ff0000'});
  }else{
    $('.cover').css({'color':'#000000'});
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="cover" style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'); width:100px; height:100px; color:#000">Div 2</div>
```

> **Here is an example:** You can run the below snippet and check in this snippet
> The DIV contains a PNG background image so on document load the text of the DIV
> will be in BLACK color
>
> ```js
> $(document).ready(function(){
>   if($('.cover').attr("style").indexOf('data:image/svg+xml') != -1){
>     $('.cover').css({'color':'#ff0000'});
>   }else{
>     $('.cover').css({'color':'#000000'});
>   }
> })
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
>
>
> <div class="cover" style="background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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'); width:100px; height:100px; color:#000">Div 2</div>
> ```

Hope this example will be helpful to you